# using [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll")] in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c#, winforms, dllimport

```
 [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll")]
 private static extern int GetTcpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable, ref int pdwSize, bool bOrder);
```

i am using this dll and calling the function as `GetTcpTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref iBytes, false)`

it is working fine in windows 7 32 bit os but not working in 64 bit os.How can i make it work in windows 7 64 bit os?

Comment: you build your application for x86 or x64?? what is the version of the dll in win64 64bit or 32bit?? , i think you must make the application the same as the library

Comment: @Ahmedsafan Platform target is Any CPU

Comment: try to change it to x64 and see if the error still exists?

Comment: Does it fail for all 64-bit machines? Looking at the documentation for GetTcpTable, it returns information for IPv4. Does the 64-bit machine have IPv4 turned on? I would think it does, but you never said what isn't actually working. Are you getting a specific error or return value from the API call? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just don't.  This function is already ably wrapped by .NET, System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace, IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections() method.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is with your signature:

```
private static extern int GetTcpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable, ref int pdwSize, bool bOrder);
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it is showing the following instead:

```
public static extern int GetTcpTable(byte[] pTcpTable, out int pdwSize, bool bOrder);
```

You are using the IntPtr, but it should be a buffer that will be filled with a [MIB_TCPTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

I tried finding articles referencing the correct way to implement all of this, but wasn't finding a whole lot. I am shocked that pinvoke.net doesn't even list GetTcpTable nor the structure I mentioned above.

**EDIT:**
You may want to take a look at `GetExtendedTcpTable()`

- [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [PInvoke Documentation](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetExtendedTcpTable.html)

I also found that there is a [GetTcpTable2()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that was introduced in Vista. It contains the same signature so maybe just see if calling this instead makes it magically work on x64 since your current call supposedly works on x86. It may not work 100% right out of the box, but I am curious if it gets you farther or at least a different result.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, but don't miss [Hans's comment to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747484/using-dllimportiphlpapi-dll-in-windows-7-64-bit#comment24124212_16747484). That also helps to explain why you can't find anything else online about how to P/Invoke this function.

Comment: (Also, be careful with the edit. There are 64-bit versions of Windows prior to Vista. Switching functions arbitrarily without a good reason *why* it fixes the problem isn't a good idea.)